# Python Code for find similarity hex points between two hex packet

Tags: python, hex

I want to find same Hex values between two packets example:

```
example 1 : 0X 34 21 56 B3

ecample 2 : 5D 75 21 98 A3
```

I want to get  "21" and "3"

Can anyone help me abouth this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through them at the same time and compare the values.

```
h1 = "0X342156B3" # Hex 1
h2 = "5D752198A3" # Hex 2
for i in range(10): # Modify the 10 to whatever value you need
    if h1[i] == h2[i]: # Check if both values are the same
        print(h1[i])
```

This would give

```
2
1
3
```

which you can then use however you want.

Comment: `10` should be `len(h1)` or something i guess

Comment: Yep! Could do `max(len(h1), len(h2))`.

Answer (score 0):

From your desired output "3" I assume you want to compare them character-wise:

```
str1 = "0X 34 21 56 B3"
str2 = "5D 75 21 98 A3"

for c1, c2 in zip(str1.replace(" ", ""),str2.replace(" ", "")):
    if c1 == c2:
        print(c1)
```